# What's the different between DataOutputStream write( int i ) and writeByte( int i )

Tags: java

If i want to send a integer through the socket, which should I use? What's the difference?

```
Socket socket=new Socket(localhost, 9876);
DataOutputStream writer=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
int i =  10;
writer.write(i);

writer.writeByte(i);
```

Do I need to add "\r\n" at the end when using writeByte?

Comment: You should be able to look at the freely available source code to see what the difference is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality is the same, they both write the eight low-level bits of the argument onto the underlying stream.

BUT writeByte is final and unsynchronized while write is not final and is synchronized

Moreover, DataOutputStream implements the DataOutput interface which contains the writeByte() and write() method and overrides write() declared in its superclass FilterOutputStream. That's the reason why DataOutputStream ends up having two different methods doing the same job...

Also Refer to [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. They do the same thing. `DataOutputStream` needs to implement `write(int)` because it's part of the `OutputStream` type.

Neither of them write any line terminators.

Comment: Do I need to add "\r\n" at the end when using writeBytes?

Comment: @Summer Why do you ask that? Do you think `write(int)` does that?

Comment: when I use writeByte to send strings "\r\n" is needed at the end.

Comment: @Summer Then please re-read my answer. They `writeByte(int)` and `write(int)` have exactly the same behavior.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain my question well. I used writer.writeBytes(i); in my code and that causes the error cuz writeBytes should be used to send strings. I'm really new to java so making all kinds of stupid mistakes.

Comment: @Summer Are you asking about `writeBytes` or `writeByte`?

Comment: NVM, I figured it out. It was a stupid mistake that I made. Thanks anyway. I'll delete this question. XD